# UIWebView scroll down

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uiwebview

I use IUWebView like chat window and after adding new message in the bottom of view I wanna scroll down view programmicaly, how can I do it?

Comment: maybe try to add script to end of html and scroll window with javascript, but how?..

Comment: <span id='bottom'/><script>document.getElementById('bottom').scrollIntoView(true)</script>

Answer (score 3):

Implement this method in your UIWebView Delegate.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollWidth, document.body.scrollHeight);"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this:

```
[mywebview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.scrollTo(x, y);"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You know there is a scroll view in UIWebView as its subview, so you can get this one, and use it to do scroll job -

```
NSArray *views = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self.webview subviews]];
self.scrollview = (UIScrollView *)[views objectAtIndex:0];
```

You can set its delegate `self.scrollview.delegate = self`, or you can use anything the UIScrollView can do, so google "UIScrollView class reference" to see what you can do for your question. Hope it helps.

Comment: This approach isn't safe under iOS 4 or earlier. However, here in the future, iOS 5 has added a `scrollView` property to `UIWebView` that can otherwise be used in the spirit of this question.